# Set list element width the text width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML bullet pointed list. How do I use CSS to make the width of the `li` element is the same as the length of the text inside the `li`.

After some searching, I tried:

```
display: inline-block;
```

But this makes all the bullet point formatting go away. (I no longer see any bullets). Is there a simple solution/alternative to this?

Comment: the question is not clear can you provide some more code and explain what you want to achieve and what's the main problem?

Comment: If you set the display for the ul to inline block, then the li's will only be as wide as the widest li... But it really depends on what you want to do.... show us a graphic or give us a clue as to what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:block`and float your `<li>`elements to the left. But this method requires some additional CSS to add the list bullets.

**Snippet**

```css
ul > li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    list-style:circle;
}
ul>li:before{
    content:"•";
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item-1</li>
    <li>Item-ABC</li>
    <li>Item-A</li>
    <li>Item-ABDAKDÖSAKD</li>
    <li>Item-AAAAA</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear, but try this approach

HTML

```
<li> Item 1 </li><br>
<li> Item 2 </li><br>
<li> Item 3 </li>
```

CSS

```
li { 
display: inline-block;
}
li:before {
content: "* ";  //you can change the special character 
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple javascript:

NOTE: I will be using an inline JavaScript, so it is parsed after the list is parsed.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>TEST</li>
</ul>
<script>
    var longestText = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++){
    if(document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].innerHTML.length > longestText.length){
    longestText = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].innerHTML;
}else {
    continue;
}
}

document.getElementById("list"). style.width = (longestText.length * document.getElementById ("list").style.font size) + " px";
</script>
```

What this does is do a programmatic search for the largest text in the list, and once found, it sets the list's width property to the text length of the largest text * the font size of the table.